# JAVA: Method that takes an int "n" as input, and returns an array that contains the first n prime numbers

Tags: java, arrays

Here is what I got so far

```
public static int[] firstPrimeNumbers(int n) { 

    int[] k = new int[n];
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

        if (isPrime(i)) { 
            k[m] = i;
            m++;
        }

    }
    return k;
}
```

Problem is, when I try to print the resulting array, I get a bunch of 0's at the end. For example when I took `n = 10`, the program printed

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Hows that even possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Hows that even possible" -> `int[] k = new int[n];` what do you think happens here?

Comment: Array k is created with the size of my number n, why? I dont see whats wrong with it

Comment: I am not saying that it is wrong, I am trying to explain "why" part. So what do you think your array contains after it was created?

Comment: Are the first `n` numbers guaranteed to be prime?

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is fairly easy.
`k` has size `10` and initially filled with zeros.

Then you check the first 10 natural numbers and check whether they are prime. 
So for each non-prime number you should get a `0`

Maybe replace `i<n` by `m<n` but that depends a bit on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Never mind I got it, silly mistake if I've ever seen one. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would need to make an animation for a better explanation. My recommendation would be to install eclipse and then use the interactive debug mode. alternatively you could visualise the output of each iteration in the for loop

Comment: Basically `i` is counting how many numbers you checked for whether they are prime. However, only the prime subset of the checked numbers go into the array.

Answer (score 1):

You are just counting until `i == n` (so only looking at number up to `n`) - you need to keep incrementing `i` until `m == n` so you are considering whether numbers > `n` are prime.

If you used better variable names like `nextPrimeIndex` or `primesFound` instead of `m` this would probably be easier to spot.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your for loop. What you are doing is actually returning in an array of `n` elements the primitive numbers less than `n`

```
 public static int[] firstPrimeNumbers(int n) { 

      int[] k = new int[n];
      int nr = 2;
      int m = 0; 
      while(m<n){
         if(isPrime(nr)){ 
           k[m] = nr;
           m++;      
        }
         nr++;
      } 
     return k;
   }
```